# Is there a way to find out whats the MaxClients value is on a live system without looking at config files

Tags: debian, apache-http-server

Right now we are setting up a Debian Server with Apache2 as Web Server. Due to the fact that different config files could have an effect on the settings, I want to output the live config file values and especially MaxClients on the command line or on a web browser.

I setup mod_info and server-status expecting that I can see the values there, but I dont seem to be able to find the correct values there.

Can anybody help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MaxClients` is a server-wide keyword, so there should be a single instance of it per `httpd` proccess (usually a single instance per Linux server). Assuming typical Debian installation, you can just grep the values:

```
 grep -r -e MaxClients -e anothervalue -e anothervalue2 /etc/apache2/ | grep -v \#
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find the information with Module [mod_info](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_info.html)

On my server I got this

```
Module Name: prefork.c
Content handlers: none
Configuration Phase Participation: none
Request Phase Participation: none
Module Directives:
User - Effective user id for this server
Group - Effective group id for this server
ChrootDir - The directory to chroot(2) into
ListenBacklog - Maximum length of the queue of pending connections, as used by listen(2)
Listen - A port number or a numeric IP address and a port number, and an optional protocol
SendBufferSize - Send buffer size in bytes
ReceiveBufferSize - Receive buffer size in bytes
StartServers - Number of child processes launched at server startup
MinSpareServers - Minimum number of idle children, to handle request spikes
MaxSpareServers - Maximum number of idle children
MaxClients - Maximum number of children alive at the same time
ServerLimit - Maximum value of MaxClients for this run of Apache
GracefulShutdownTimeout - Maximum time in seconds to wait for child processes to complete transactions during shutdown
Current Configuration:
In file: /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
 133: StartServers 5
 134: MinSpareServers 5
 135: MaxSpareServers 10
 136: MaxClients 150
 178: User www-data
 179: Group www-data
In file: /etc/apache2/ports.conf
   9: Listen 80
  17: Listen 443
```